# OpenJDK 11's HttpClient causes "Too many files opened" exception when create multiple instances

Tags: java

I'm trying to use HttpClient from JDK 11 by following the example from this link https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html. My code is simply to call an API multiple times. It looks like following:

```
for(int x=0; x < 3000; ++x) {
   HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
   HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
      .uri(URI.create("http://example.com/"))
      .build();
   client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
      .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
      .thenAccept(System.out::println);
}
```

This code causes an `IOException` at `HttpClient.newHttpClient()`

```
java.lang.InternalError: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.<init>(HttpClientImpl.java:311)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.create(HttpClientImpl.java:253)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientBuilderImpl.build(HttpClientBuilderImpl.java:135)
    at java.net.http/java.net.http.HttpClient.newHttpClient(HttpClient.java:158)
...
```

I'm running it on Ubuntu 18.04.1 with file handle limit = 1024.

I figure out that the problem is solved if I create `HttpClient` instance once. But I need that `HttpClient` in many places of my project and I don't want to to make a global variable for it.  Is there a way to create local `HttpClient` without causing this problem?

Comment: you need more than thousand simultaneously open connections to some other service? Just making sure...

Comment: Use a dependency injection framework to inject the same HttpClient object wherever you need it.

Comment: @malejpavouk On Ubuntu it takes around 100-200 iterations to hit the file open limit (1024 in my case).

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thank you for suggestion. But part of the code is in a shared library which I plan to use it with other project. I'm not sure if I can avoid the DI in the lib.

Comment: I get this issue as well even if I cache the HttpClient, I'm a little confused about it.